# JEST - node server having trouble during start

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have one node application which have a file called server.js where I run 
`node server.js env=feature port=8081` to start the node server. 
I installed jest and supertest. After writing one async get call in `sample.test.js` file I am hitting `npm test`, But the result is not as expected. Because to start server.js I will pass two parameters called env and port as mentioned above. My question is, How to use it in Jest. My server importing code is present below

```
const app = require('../server.js')
const request = supertest(app)
describe('Sample Test', () => {
const response = await request.get("/rest/api/v1/mytools/getAvailableTools?provisioning=all");
    console.log('James bob ' + JSON.stringify(response))
    expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(401);
    done()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways how you can approach this.

First, it's a common practice to pass such values using environment variables, you would have to update code processing those values but at the end, you can do the following:

```sh
ENV=feature PORT=8081 node server.js
ENV=feature PORT=8081 npm test
```

The second option would be to decouple command line parameters from actual server and test them separately, e.g.

```js
export const createServer(env, port) {
  // Server code
}

// Command line processing code

createServer(cliEnv, cliPort)
```

So in tests you can write:

```js
const createServer = require('../server.js')
const request = supertest(createServer('feature', 8081))
describe('Sample Test', () => {
const response = await request.get("/rest/api/v1/mytools/getAvailableTools?provisioning=all");
    console.log('James bob ' + JSON.stringify(response))
    expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(401);
    done()
})
```